# RecyclerView items sometimes do not display correctly until I scroll (Only on Genymotion Tablets)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, genymotion

I'm working on a simple restaurant POS system, and I had a problem suddenly come up. This problem has only occurred when I run it on a Genymotion tablet device. I do not have this problem on smaller genymotion devices or the 2 physical devices I've tried.

One of my activities uses 5 RecyclerViews to display the menu and sales summary. Every few item clicks, the RecyclerViews decide to just not update and do not properly display my items unless I scroll a bit on ANY of the RecyclerViews or click something. Even though they are not displayed properly, all item clicks register what should be shown (not what is actually shown).

For example, I click beef -> seafood -> chicken. The RecyclerView responsible for showing the menu items still shows seafood. If I click on anything, the correct chicken item gets selected and everything refreshes to what should show up. If I scroll on any RecyclerView (even an unrelated one), everything refreshes properly.

Activity onCreate():

```
    ...

    cAdapter = new CategoryAdapter();
    cAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickAdapter<Category>() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Category item, int position) {
            miAdapter.setItems(item.getMenuItems());
            va1.setDisplayedChild(0);
        }
    });

    miAdapter = new MenuItemAdapter();
    miAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickAdapter<MenuItem>() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(MenuItem item, int position) {
            salesOrder.addMenuItem(item);
            oeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            updateTotals();
        }
    });

    ...
```

Adapters:

```
 public abstract class ItemRecyclerViewAdapter<T, TVH extends ItemViewHolder<T>> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TVH> {

    private ItemViewHolder.OnItemClickListener<T> listener;
    protected List<T> items;

    public ItemRecyclerViewAdapter() {
        this(new ArrayList<T>());
    }

    public ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public final void setOnItemClickListener(ItemViewHolder.OnItemClickListener<T> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void setItems(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.items.clear();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    protected abstract TVH createItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

    @Override
    public TVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        TVH holder = createItemViewHolder(parent, viewType);
        holder.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TVH holder, int position) {
        holder.setItem(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

ViewHolders:

```
public abstract class ItemViewHolder<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener<T> {
        void onItemClick(T item, int position);
        boolean onItemLongClick(T item, int position);
    }

    public final void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener<T> listener) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onItemClick(getItem(), getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return listener != null && listener.onItemLongClick(getItem(), getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }

    public abstract T getItem();

    public abstract void setItem(T item);

}
```

It SEEMS like it's a swapbuffer issue or some race condition I'm not seeing, but I thought I'd see if maybe I'm misunderstanding something first. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have the same issue on Samsung s2 and samsung s3 genymotion devices - RecyclerView does not work, (update actually), untill i scroll it a bit.. You thionk it's a bug of genymotion?

Comment: It seems like it. It isn't happening all the time, just most of the time. It's weird because it works exactly like it's supposed to in the background, but it just doesn't display it properly. Sometimes, it'll suddenly display after minimizing/reopening the emulator.

Comment: Terry, i have fixed that bug. I do not how, but that bug depended from my keyboard listener, and transformations to my bottom layout. I have changed that listener to more smart one, and no bugs are on androids 4.0 - 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I have that bug too.
After editing my activity_main.xml, I could fix it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ulimbridge.recylerview.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Making RecyclerViews' height and width '0dp' was a solution.